# How can I display a file directory in Android?

Tags: android, listview

Need help on how to display this activity view inside our app .

[image: this activity view]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to build a layout for Android? Have you read about Recyclerview?https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: First off all Android is NOT equal to Android Studio IDE. Screenshot is enough to verify what do you have tried so far. You need to [edit] and post some [mcve] here.

Comment: @Shashanth Okay sir my bad already edited

Comment: ok, which kind of help you need? What exactly is a problem?

Comment: @RoRa Nothing sir . i mean im just starting

Comment: Want i want sir is after i click a button. I want to show that kind of view inside my application . so that the user can able to see those files without going outside the app

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Want i want sir is after i click a button. I want to show that kind of view inside my application . so that the user can able to see those files without going outside the app

Comment: I already see what you want, but I asked **what is a problem**? What stops you from doing what you want? You can't just ask us to write entire application instead of you. So specify what exactly is a problem.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko iam currently checking whats Rora link and trying to make a  list view like that . I just want to know if its possible ?

Comment: sure, it is possible.

Comment: O nice good to hear  sir thanks heehe